# Cookie not working

Tags: php, cookies

i would like that when someone goes on a link it executes my Cookie.
Here is my code

```
<?php
$globalpass = "Cuk@4Kk@Lx&?sFu}k]";
     $one_year = time()+(60*60*24*365);
 setcookie('password', sha1($globalpass), $one_year);
     print_r($_COOKIE);
 ?>
```

That is it it is the only code... so how come the cookie does not work?

Comment: Well the cookie is not added when i go in my browser...

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)..

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the **next page
>   load** with the $_COOKIE

So you cannot try to print that  on the very same page. **It will be available on the other page**

Also, see...

Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.

Comment: So how should i do it? :)

Comment: reload the page if you need to